# DRF python ReturnList to JSON

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to query informaticon and then I want to loop through that information to get certain data.
The point is that when I try to go through the item "data" in the console I get a message saying

> AttributeError: object 'ReturnList' has no attribute 'elements'

when I do `type (data)` I get the following:

```
<class 'rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnList'>
```

Without the for (no errors) the information arrives as a JSON to the front.
`[{id: 1, photo: null ..}, {id: 2, photo: null ..} ... etc]`

viewSet code:

```
class TecnicosViewSet(
        mixins.CreateModelMixin,
        mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
        mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
        mixins.ListModelMixin,
        mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
        viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = Tecnico.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Tecnicoserializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Tecnico.objects.all()
        serializer_class = Tecnicoserializer(queryset, many=True)
        data = serializer_class.data
        print(type(data))
        # for index, item in data.items():
        #     print('II', index)

        return Response(data)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "when I try to go through the item "data" in the console"?

Comment: when I make the request from the frontend, in the server console it shows me that error when the for loop is executed

Comment: please post your frontend code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is a `list` and not `dict`, so there is no `.items()` method available. You have to iterate through it like this:

```py
for item in data:
    print(item)
```

If you really need index, do this:

```py
for index in range(len(data)):
    print('II', index)
    # Get item as data[index]
```